# Outline Css Property does not work in Outlook

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to apply outline dotted `CSS` on a `span` tag but in outlook email it does not appear.

[image: desired result]

HTML-

```
<p style='color: #282728; line-height: 1.5'>
      <span style='line-height: 34px'>USE THIS CODE</span>
      <span style="vertical-align:middle; font-size: 24px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#597b48; color:#000000; outline-style:dotted; outline-color: #000000; padding:0 5px;">FIRST5</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use outline? The same effect can be achieved by using border

Comment: I agree with Jiří, the outline is likely not there either because outlook is blocking it, rather to stop content in an email body being confused with the app interface. Border is a valid alternative.

Comment: It is ill-advised to use `outline`  as `border` for accessibility purposes. As suggested before, use `border` instead. Alternatively you can use `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black` if you don't want the line to consume outside space.

Comment: Thanks Jiří Melen it worked using border.